# Как добавить группировку в NSCollectionView?

Tags: cocoa, macos, xcode

Есть какой-нибудь способ разбить NSCollectionView на секции?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, копайте в сторону

```
- collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:
```

Я юзаю лайауты от: [CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout), там стик хедеры реализованы, да и Хедер коллекции с паралакс эффектом.

**UPD**

Ответ относится к iOS, для mac OS X проблемму решают [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370125/nscollectionview-with-sections-like-in-iphoto).

Comment: Это только для iOS? Мне для десктопа нужно, т.е. для Mac OS X.

Comment: Ой, наверное, да :(, но я думаю, там не долого расскурить и прикрутить аналогично к Mac Os X

Comment: Мой отет вам полностью не подходит, поищите здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370125/nscollectionview-with-sections-like-in-iphoto

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую полностью отказаться от использования `NSCollectionView`, потому что этот компонент не использует механизм переиспользования ячеек и имеет очень ограниченный и неудобный интерфейс.

[Есть очень неплохая замена](https://github.com/jwilling/JNWCollectionView), смоделированная на манер современного NSTableView.

[`JNWCollectionView`](https://github.com/jwilling/JNWCollectionView) с лейаутом [`JNWCollectionViewGridLayout`](https://github.com/jwilling/JNWCollectionView/blob/master/JNWCollectionView/JNWCollectionViewGridLayout.h) позволит без лишних трудностей реализовать «матрицу» из кастомных элементов, включая разбиение на секции.